# Is there a way to force a bone to snap to fixed-step rotation?

Tags: armature, bones, transforms, constraints

As in, is it possible for me to set up an armature so that a bone's X-rotation will snap to, say, 30°, -30°, or some multiple of 60° from there? I'm working on a toggle switch, and while I can manually ensure this, I feel like it would be just like constraints to have solved this problem for me.

In other words, if you rotate it to 15° on X, it will snap to 30°; but if you rotate it to, say -17°, it will snap to -30°, which is closer. It feels like it would be easy to implement in Python, but that usually means that someone's already done it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know whether this is possible with just 1 bone, but if you create a helper bone, you can use that helper bone to move your rotation and this will make the other bone jump in 30 degrees like this:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Drivers are an excellent solution, thank you. I still feel like this would be well-served by a constraint, but then, a lot of different things probably are!